# Getting Array Data

Tags: php, arrays

The following is a profile array printed using `r_print`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Profile
            [Name] => Veritas
            [NKey] => Key_1
            [SKey] => Key_2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Access
            [Admin] => True
            [Banned] => False
            [Public] => True
        )

)
```

What I'm trying to do, is simply retrieve elements of that array.

IE,

```
$profile[] = ...; //GET_ARRAY
$user = $profile[0]['Name'];
$key_1 = $profile[0]['NKey'];
$key_2 = $profile[0]['SKey'];
$admin = $profile[1]['Admin'];
```

For some reason, the above code doesn't work, though logically it should work without a problem.
What **IS** returned, is just the character 'A' if I target anything within the array.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding another level to your array by assigning the array to `$profile[]`. The brackets turn `$profile` into an array and then adds that array to it causing the extra level.

```
$profile[] = ...; //GET_ARRAY
```

should just be

```
$profile = ...; //GET_ARRAY
```

Comment: Thanks for that tip, though even with a dimension removed, I still can't seem to access data from any elements.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what I was looking for, thought PHP automatically formated arrays (string data) passed from another page. I solved my issue using *serialize()* & *unserialize()*.